# How to erase eyebrows in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to erase eyebrows from face very much like in the example photos. Eventually I will automate the process with code. I need to find a way that would give the results like in the examples and would work with different skin colors as well as eyebrow colors. 
[image: Input Image]

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the **healing brush tool** to first sample from the forehead (hold alt and click) and then remove the eyebrows by drawing over them.

[image: removing eyebrows using healing brush tool]

However, it might be hard to automate this using code. My best guess would be to use [landmark detection](http://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/) to find the eyebrows in an image and then use [inpainting](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html) to remove them.